# I want request.POST[variable name] to be executed only if the variable name exists in the input of template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

```
def sendorder(request):

    items = MenuModel.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for item in items:
            if request.POST['item'+str(item.id)]:
                print(request.POST['item'+str(item.id)])

    return
```

I have some inputs in templates with name item2,item3 etc etc, but this view counts right from the beginning item1 which gives error as no input with name item1 exists. I want to bypass if no such input name exists.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than bypassing it, Try to pass the ids in an `array` to the view. And query accordingly.

For example:

```
id_list = request.POST['id_list']  # if you pass id array with key id_list
items = MenuModel.objects.filter(id__in=id_list)
for item in items:
    print(request.POST['item'+str(item.id)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to first see if there is anything and if there is then do something. So you are checking, in this case use the try and except method. Assuming you have already experimented to see if you get anything from the request. (You could also do a mix of mohammed's answer) This is how it would go.
Here's a link for an example on its uses. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

```
for items in item:
    try request.POST['item'+str(item.id)]:
        //do something
    except:
        //Except was hit cause no item1 exists. Maybe run a print to be sure
```